# NavigationView get/find header layout

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-design-library, navigationview

In my NavigationView I have a header layout with id 'viewId' with active buttons. To setup those buttons, I do the following in activity's `onPostCreate`:

```
final View panel = findViewById(R.id.viewId);
panel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
... setup goes here ...
});
```

With new version android support library, (**23.1.0**), the view can't be found, it returns null. With previous versions it worked well. Is it a bug or am I using this feature wrong? If so, how to access header layout and add behavior to it?

Answer (score 456, accepted):

Version 23.1.0 switches `NavigationView` to using a `RecyclerView` (rather than the previous `ListView`) and the header is added as one of those elements. This means it is not instantly available to call `findViewById()` - a layout pass is needed before it is attached to the `NavigationView`.

For [version 23.1.1](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/ebXLByBiEBU) of the Support Library, you can now get a reference to the header view using `getHeaderView()`:

```
View headerLayout = navigationView.getHeaderView(0); // 0-index header
```

This has the advantage of working on headers added via XML and via code.

If you are still using 23.1.0, as per [the related bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=190226), you can inflate the header in code and use `findViewById()` on that:

```
View headerLayout = 
    navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.navigation_header);
panel = headerLayout.findViewById(R.id.viewId);
// panel won't be null
```

Until you move to 23.1.1.

Comment: `OnLayoutChangeListener` requires min sdk level 11, but I have 9 in my app. Any ideas please, how to workaround `findViewById` returning `null` for `NavigationView` header?

Comment: @AlexanderFarber - the code I posted works back to API 7

Comment: I prefer to downgrade libs. Introducing a bug is like a signature from Google. If the new version has a bug, then Google released that new version

Comment: @GFPF - the accepted answer is strictly worse (`inflate(R.layout.lay_header, null);` will cause all `layout_` attributes to be ignored, while this solution does not) and accomplishes the same result.

Comment: @ianhanniballake This is true, but  the method [inflateHeaderView](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html#inflateHeaderView(int)) has not any overloading that consider set header view with "attachToRoot" true in method [inflate](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean)).

How to solve it in the best way without ignoring the attributes?

Comment: @GFPF - when you call `inflateHeaderView`, it attaches the View for you in the correct layer in the `RecyclerView` with the correct parent - something that you cannot do externally to `NavigationView`.

Comment: This method comes with the issue that if the header is already defined inside the xml file, calling inflateheader adds an extra header in the side drawer.

Comment: @RmK - thanks, I've updated to answer to reflect the new APIs added in 23.1.1 to retrieve headers added via XML (as the previous workaround only worked on headers added via code).

Comment: I really like how Google changes major part of view control in each and every sdk update, not.

Comment: `getHeaderView(0)`.. i thought that the 0 the the index of the View but it's obvious that it is not, thanks.

Answer (score 152):

Now with the 23.1.1 release of the design support library, you can use

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.your_nav_view_id);
View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0)
TextView text = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

Comment: You can also use `navigationView.getHeaderCount()` in case you have more than 1 header for whatever reason.

Answer (score 14):

This is how I did it using `ButterKnife` and it works for me.

```
protected static class HeaderViewHolder {

    @BindView(R.id.button)
    Button button;

    HeaderViewHolder(View view) {
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    }
}
```

and then use this view holder like this :

```
View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
headerViewHolder = new HeaderViewHolder(header);
```

Comment: This is perfect when you want to remove View related logic from your Activity. Great idea!

Comment: Its working perfectly with ButterKnife,thanks brother.

Answer (score 9):

For me that was the same situation with 23.1.0, after of update the null pointer exception become. In this case the `NavigatorView` look like:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
  android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="start"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
  app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
  app:menu="@menu/menu_nav"/>
```

I tried the solution proposal by ianhanniballake but it does not work.  Then I inflated with the sentence:

```
LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.nav_header, mNavigationView);
```

After that, I can find by id  all views defined in `nav_heard`layout .

Answer (score 5):

```
NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.your_nav_view);
View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
TextView textUsername = header.findViewById(R.id.textView);
textUsername.setText("you text here ")
```

Answer (score 4):

```
NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.your_nav_view);
View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
TextView textUsername = header.findViewById(R.id.textView);
textUsername.setText("you text here ");
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please add some text explaining how this solves the question asked above.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin @Francois Dermu code be like

```
val navigationView : NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.your_nav_view_id);
val header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0)
val textView = header.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
```

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin version.

```
val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)       
// set User Name
val headerView: View = navView.getHeaderView(0)
headerView.txtUserName.text = "User Name Goes here"
```

Answer (score 1):

Works for me in java

```
   navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    View viewHeader = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    ((TextView)viewHeader.findViewById(R.id.tv_name)).setText(preferences.getString(MyConstant.NAME,"n/a"));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is how to change a username in a drawer.**

```
NavigationView mNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
View mHeaderView = mNavigationView.getHeaderView(0);
TextView usernameTextview = mHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.drawer_email_textField);
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
String username = b.getString("email");
usernameTextview.setText(username);
```

that's works for me