# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required view not found even after setContentView()

Tags: android-layout, android-activity, illegalstateexception, setcontentview

I am facing a weird problem related to view not found but everything seems to be right with the code (at least to me). Infact the program was working fine till some time back. I am not sure what change that i made causing this issue. Could anyone of you point me the problem? Thank you.

The below is the exception trace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                Process: co.mycompany, PID: 3923
                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{co.mycompany/co.mycompany.activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to bind views for co.mycompany.activities.MainActivity
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2201)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1213)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5065)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to bind views for co.mycompany.activities.MainActivity
                                                                    at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:322)
                                                                    at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:237)
                                                                    at co.mycompany.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:51)
                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5249)
                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2165)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1213) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5065) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609) 
                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required view 'thUserProfilePic' with ID 2131558656 for field 'mUserProfilePic' was not found. If this view is optional add '@Nullable' annotation.
                                                                    at butterknife.ButterKnife$Finder.findRequiredView(ButterKnife.java:140)
                                                                    at co.mycompany.activities.MainActivity$$ViewBinder.bind(MainActivity$$ViewBinder.java:17)
                                                                    at co.mycompany.activities.MainActivity$$ViewBinder.bind(MainActivity$$ViewBinder.java:8)
                                                                    at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:319)
                                                                    at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:237) 
                                                                    at co.mycompany.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:51) 
                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5249) 
                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2165) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1213) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5065) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609) 
                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

MainActivity.class

```
@Bind(R.id.thUserProfilePic)
CircleImageView mUserProfilePic;
@Bind(R.id.thUserDisplayName)
TextView mUserDisplayName;
@Bind(R.id.editProfileLink)
ImageView editProfileLink;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);


    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, mDrawerLayout, mToolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    navigate(AppScreen.HOME);

}
```

R.layout.activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include layout="@layout/app_bar_main" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main" app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
        android:background="@color/white"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

R.layout.nav_header_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/editProfileLink"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_edit_white_24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end|right"/>

    <include layout="@layout/user_thumbnail_large"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

R.layout.user_thumnail_large

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/userThumbnailLargeContainer">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView android:layout_width="75dp" android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_face_white_48dp" android:id="@+id/thUserProfilePic" />

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing" android:text="John"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:id="@+id/thUserDisplayName"
        android:textColor="@color/textColorSecondary"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I am into second day of research and could not able to figure out what the issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with support Library version. I was getting the above error since i upgraded support library to 23 version.

The below link has the solution.

[NavigationView get/find header layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33194594/navigationview-get-find-header-layout)