# java.lang.IllegalStateException Butterknife

Tags: android, android-activity, butterknife

I am facing `java.lang.IllegalStateException Required view 'splash_text'` but I have included it in the xml.

I am using `Butterknife` to Bind the views.

```
 compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
```

Xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light">

<com.CustomTextView
    android:id="@+id/splash_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity :

```
@Bind(R.id.splash_text)
CustomTextView mSplashTv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    mSplashTv.setText("Splash");

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            finishSplash();
        }
    },3000);
}
```

Application is crashing at the line `mSplashTv.setText("Splash");`

Log :

```
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required view 'splash_text' with ID 2131492944 for field 'mSplashTv' was not found. If this view is optional add '@Nullable' annotation.
  at butterknife.ButterKnife$Finder.findRequiredView(ButterKnife.java:140)
  at com.sonymix.activities.SplashActivity$$ViewBinder.bind(SplashActivity$$ViewBinder.java:12)
  at com.sonymix.activities.SplashActivity$$ViewBinder.bind(SplashActivity$$ViewBinder.java:9)
  at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:319)
  at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:237) 
  at com.sonymix.activities.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:16) 
  at com.sonymix.activities.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:33) 
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372) 
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:165) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1326) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003) 
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Update:

BaseActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
}
```

Support Library used:

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
```

Comment: Please post `onCreate` of `BaseActivity`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NavigationView get/find header layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33194594/navigationview-get-find-header-layout)

Comment: Try removing `ButterKnife.bind(this);` from `BaseActivity`.

Comment: I tried. Still facing same issue.

Comment: Not sure but smell like support library dependency issue and show your base application

Comment: you are extending a base activity. Have you overridden `setContentView` in `BaseActivity`? Because anywhere if binding call comes before setContentView, it would fail.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove binding from base activity. When ButterKnife bind in base class, your layout not inflated yet.
Also you can add **@Nullable** annotation to field.

Comment: Adding the `@Nullable` to the field fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

It's because your layout **is not inflated yet**. If you are using **BaseActivity**, do something like this :

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(this.getLayoutContentViewID());
        ButterKnife.bind(this); //Configure Butterknife
    }

    public abstract int getLayoutContentViewID();

}
```

Next, in your **MainActivity** :

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.main_activity_coordinator_layout) CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;

    ...

    @Override
    public int getLayoutContentViewID() { return R.layout.activity_main; }
    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your support Library version. I was getting the above error since i upgraded support library to 23 version. may be that is causing error.[NavigationView get/find header layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33194594/navigationview-get-find-header-layout)