# FlowingDrawer Sample does not run

Tags: java, android, gradle, build, navigation-drawer

I tried to run the sample of this library : 
https://github.com/mxn21/FlowingDrawer

it works fine with this outdated build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mt.stackoverflow"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 120
        versionName "1.2.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.+'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.mxn.soul:flowingdrawer-core:1.2.2'
}
```

but it fails with this updated build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mt.stackoverflow"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 120
        versionName "1.2.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.mxn.soul:flowingdrawer-core:1.2.2'
}
```

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                         Process: com.mt.stackoverflow, PID: 31453
>                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.mt.stackoverflow/com.mt.stackoverflow.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be
>   null.
>                                                                             at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:607)
>                                                                             at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:590)
>                                                                             at
>   com.mt.stackoverflow.MyMenuFragment.setupHeader(MyMenuFragment.java:44)
>                                                                             at
>   com.mt.stackoverflow.MyMenuFragment.onCreateView(MyMenuFragment.java:31)
>                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
>                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
>                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
>                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
>                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
>                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:339)
>                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:602)
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237)
>                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6268)
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422) 
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Any ideas how I can run the sample with the moste recent build.gradle dependencies ?

Comment: show MyMenuFragment.java:

Answer (score 1):

The project is trying to access the `ImageView` in the header of the `NavigationView` in `fragment_menu.xml` in a way that is not compatible with the newer version of the support library. You can find the details in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33194594/navigationview-get-find-header-layout).

The `ImageView` is used as the `target` in a `Picasso` call and since the `ImageView` can no longer be found it is null and that is the cause of the `IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null` error.

To fix it open the class `MyMenuFragment` and replace `onCreateView(...)` with the following:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false);

    View header = ((NavigationView) view.findViewById(R.id.vNavigation)).getHeaderView(0);
    ivMenuUserProfilePhoto = (ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.ivMenuUserProfilePhoto);

    setupHeader();
    return setupReveal(view) ;
}
```

Basically you can no longer find `ivMenuUserProfilePhoto` directly from `view`. You first need to get the header view from the `NavigationView` and then find the `ImageView` using the header.