# setText in another layout

Tags: java, android, xml

So I'm having a little bit of trouble trying to change the text of a `TextView` in another layout. My `MainActivity.java` sets the content view as `activity_main.xml`, which `<include>`s `app_bar_main.xml`, which `<include>`s `content_main.xml`, where my main app layout is displayed (it's a Navigation Drawer Activity in Android Studio).

Part of my code in `MainActivity.java` is shown below:

```
String user, organisation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Default code to include navigation drawer here

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (bundle != null) {
            user = bundle.getString("user");
            organisation = bundle.getString("organisation");

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View hamburgerMenu = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_header_main, null);

            TextView navUsername = (TextView) hamburgerMenu.findViewById(R.id.nav_username),
                    navOrgGroup = (TextView) hamburgerMenu.findViewById(R.id.orgGroup);

            navUsername.setText(user);
            navOrgGroup.setText(organisation);
        }
    }
}
```

And my `nav_header_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:contentDescription="@string/user"
        android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nav_username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="@string/user"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/orgGroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/email" />
</LinearLayout>
```

But for some reason the `TextView`s in `nav_header_main.xml` never changes. It remains as the default values set in the XML file. Why is this so? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since you're not getting any `NullPointerException`s you've initialized the `TextViews` well. Now can you just try `.setText("anything");` instead of `user` since it may be empty or something.

Comment: I've added a Snackbar right after setText and I can be sure that `user` and `organisation` are not `null`

Comment: In my code I'm using somewhat of a different strategy to change the `TextView` in the navigation drawer. `View v = navigationView.getHeaderView(0); TextView emailTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.emailTextView);` Might you try this approach?

Comment: @Vucko It worked! Do upload your comment as an answer so that I can accept it. Will be good if you can explain the code too :)

Comment: Thanks mate. I linked a question that explains this in my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my comment helped solve:

> In my code I'm using somewhat of a different strategy to change the TextView in the navigation drawer. `View v = navigationView.getHeaderView(0); TextView emailTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.emailTextView);`

As for the explanation, you might take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33194594/navigationview-get-find-header-layout). It'd be redundant that I copy the text here.

Answer (score 0):

your hamburgerMenu has inflated but not add to any viewGroup to show it