# no suitable method found for findViewById(TextView)

Tags: android, findviewbyid

> Error:(43, 35) error: no suitable method found for findViewById(TextView)
>       method Activity.findViewById(int) is not applicable
>       (argument mismatch; TextView cannot be converted to int)
>       method AppCompatActivity.findViewById(int) is not applicable
>       (argument mismatch; TextView cannot be converted to int)

Why this error occurred in this code:

```
 lblName = (TextView) findViewById(lblName);
 lblEmail = (TextView) findViewById(lblEmail);
```

Comment: its not spam its my problam

Comment: Are you using Activity or Fragment? For activity, you need to call `setContentView()` and for Fragment, you need to use LayoutView returned by `onViewCreated()` : `returnedLayout.findViewById(...)`

Comment: i am using activity.

Comment: No i am use this textView in nav_header.xml file so how i can use this @rupinderjeet @K Neeraj Lal

Comment: You need to inflate layouts with LayoutInflator unless `nav_header.xml` is an xml preference file.

Comment: Are those `TextView`s in a `NavigationView` header layout? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33194594/navigationview-get-find-header-layout

Answer (score 1):

The argument of `findViewById` should be an id like `R.id.id_in_xml`. You are passing a variable that is already defined as `TextView` as an argument of `findViewById`, hence the error.

You should write it as follows.

```
lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblName);
lblEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblEmail);
```

**I'm not sure of the ids, you may have to change it.**

Also Make sure the id is right and the `TextView` exists in the xml file. If it doesn't you **will** run into a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference   its show this error

Comment: In your TextView, define an ID : `android:id="@+id/lblName"`

Comment: Yes i done that its shows this  --- java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lblName" />

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lblEmail" />

Answer (score 0):

You need to write-
Name  = (TextView)findviewbyid(R.id.name);

So just right R.id before sepicifying the Id name