# TextView.setText() Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, android, mobile, textview, settext

I'm currently facing a problem when trying to edit the text of a `TextView` in the `OnCreate` method of an `Activity`. As I understand, `setContentView` must be called before trying to change the text, however I am still having trouble with this.

Here is the code in question :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dash_board);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    userEmailtext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.emailText);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    userEmailtext.setText("This Does Not Work");
}
```

This `Activity` includes the `Android Studio` default sliding menu. The aim of this `setText` is to change the email address text of the sliding menu. I believe the problem may lie in the fact that the sliding menu is part of a different layout file, meaning there is no "emailText" textview leading to the `null pointer exception`, however I am still not sure how this would be rectified.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should init your TextView instace from NavigationView. In your case:

```
userEmailtext = (TextView) navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.emailText);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, works perfectly! Would you please explain the use of the number 0 in the getHeaderView method, does it act as some sort of index?

Comment: Yeah, you can read this answer to complete the information. Greetings. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33194816/4871526

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where is your `R.id.emailText` component.

If it is directly in your `R.layout.activity_dash_board`, the code should work.
If it is in R.id.nav_view, you should reach it via `navigationView.findViewById(R.id.emailText)`