# Navigation view seems to be null

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, navigationview

I've got this navigation view in a navigation drawer, in which I try to set some text to several TextViews I have in my navigation view. The thing is that in other activities it worked perfectly, but somehow in this one is not working correctly. The error appears when I call the setNavigationDrawer method and tries to set the text to the navigation view components.

```
06-07 18:37:36.658 16792-16792/pds.pdsandroid E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                            Process: pds.pdsandroid, PID: 16792
                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{pds.pdsandroid/pds.pdsandroid.Perfil}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                                                             Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                at pds.pdsandroid.Perfil.setNavigationDrawer(Perfil.java:109)
                                                                at pds.pdsandroid.Perfil.onCreate(Perfil.java:35)
                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

And this is my code:

```
package pds.pdsandroid;

public class Perfil extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private CinematlasApp mCinematlasApp;

private ImageView nav_imatge;
private TextView nav_nom;
private TextView nav_username;
private TextView nav_correu;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
private NavigationView navView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_perfil);

    mCinematlasApp = ((CinematlasApp)this.getApplication());
    setNavigationDrawer();

    ImageView mevaVista = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_perfil);
    mevaVista.setImageResource(R.drawable.imatge_perfil);

    FillData(mCinematlasApp.getUser());

}

private void setNavigationDrawer(){
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout,R.string.Open,R.string.Close);
    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();
    navView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    //SharedPreferences mSettings = getSharedPreferences(APP_SHARED_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    User user = mCinematlasApp.getUser();
    nav_imatge = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.navDrawer_imgPerfil);
    nav_nom = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.navDrawer_nom);
    nav_username = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.navDrawer_username);
    nav_correu = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.navDrawer_correu);

    nav_nom.setText(user.name+" "+user.surnames);
    nav_username.setText(user.username);
    nav_correu.setText(user.email);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    Intent intent = null;
    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.drawer_home:
            intent = new Intent(Perfil.this,Home.class);
            break;
        case R.id.drawer_perfil:
            intent = new Intent(Perfil.this,Perfil.class);
            break;
        case R.id.drawer_llistes:
            intent = new Intent(Perfil.this,Llistes.class);
            break;
        case R.id.drawer_sortir:
            mCinematlasApp.logout();
            intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Login.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            break;
    }
    if(intent!=null){
        startActivity(intent);
        if(!mCinematlasApp.isLogged())
            finish();
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

This is my body xml file:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent">

<!--IMATGE TOP-->
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                             android:layout_height="220dp" android:id="@+id/layout_imatgeTop"
>
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/atat"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    />

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/filtre8"
            android:alpha="0.4"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
<!--PERFIL PRINCIPAL-->

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="0dp"
              app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/layout_imatgeTop"
              android:layout_marginTop="219dp"
              android:background="@color/cinematlas_backgroundLightGrey"
              android:gravity="center"
              app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
              app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
              android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
              app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:id="@+id/layout_main">
    <!--NOM-->
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="40dp"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:gravity="center"
                  android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"
    >
        <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Nom"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/nom" android:contentDescription="nom" tools:text="nom"
        />

        <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/drawable_back_textview2"
                android:id="@+id/nom_passat" android:contentDescription="nom_passat" tools:text="nom_passat"
        />


        <!--COGNOMS-->


        <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Cognoms"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/cognoms" android:contentDescription="Cognoms" tools:text="Cognoms"
        />

        <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/drawable_back_textview2"
                android:id="@+id/cognoms_passat" android:contentDescription="cognoms_passat"
                tools:text="cognoms_passat"
        />


        <!--NICKNAME-->


        <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Nom d'usuari"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/nickname" android:contentDescription="nickname" tools:text="nickname"
        />

        <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/drawable_back_textview2"
                android:id="@+id/nickname_passat" android:contentDescription="nickname_passat"
                tools:text="nickname_passat"
        />


        <!--CORREU-->


        <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Correu electrònic"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/correu" android:contentDescription="correu" tools:text="correu"
        />

        <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/drawable_back_textview2"
                android:id="@+id/correu_passat" android:contentDescription="correu_passat"
                tools:text="correu_passat"
        />


        <!--PAIS-->

        <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="País"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/pais" android:contentDescription="pais" tools:text="pais"
        />

        <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/drawable_back_textview2"
                android:id="@+id/pais_passat" android:contentDescription="pais_passat" tools:text="pais_passat"
        />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout >
<!--IMATGE PERFIL-->
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout android:layout_width="150dp"
                                             android:layout_height="150dp"
                                             app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                                             app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                                             app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/layout_imatgeTop"
                                             android:layout_marginTop="138dp" android:id="@+id/layout_imatgePerfil">
    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView_perfil"
            app:civ_border_color="@color/cinematlas_secondaryDarkColor"
            app:civ_border_width="3dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
<!--BOTO EDITAR-->
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:text="Editar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button_editar"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/layout_imatgeTop"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"/>
<Button
        android:text="Sortir"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button_logout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/layout_main" android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp" app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
```

And this is my whole xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
                                        tools:context=".Perfil"
>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout...>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                                  android:background="@color/colorBlanc"
                                                  app:itemTextColor="@color/cinematlas_secondaryDarkColor"
                                                  app:itemIconTint="@color/cinematlas_primaryDarkColor"
                                                  app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"
                                                  android:layout_gravity="start"
                                                  android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
                                                  app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_drawer_header"
    >

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And my navigation drawer code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="170dp"
 >

<!--BACKGROUND-->
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/nav_background"
>
    <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="@drawable/cinema"
               android:alpha="0.8"
    />

    <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="#b18d6e63"
    />

</RelativeLayout>

<!--MAIN INFO-->
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:padding="20dp"
              android:layout_centerInParent="true">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:src="@drawable/imatge_perfil"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:id="@+id/navDrawer_imgPerfil"
            app:civ_border_color="@color/cinematlas_primaryLightColor"
            app:civ_border_width="2dp"/>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:layout_marginTop="8dp"

    >
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:id="@+id/navDrawer_nom"
                  android:textStyle="bold"
                  android:textColor="@color/cinematlas_secondaryDarkColor"
                  android:text="Nom"
        />

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:id="@+id/navDrawer_username"
                  android:textColor="@color/cinematlas_primaryTextColor"
                  android:text="Username"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        />
    </LinearLayout>


    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/navDrawer_correu"
              android:textColor="@color/cinematlas_primaryTextColor"
              android:textStyle="italic"
              android:text="Correu electrònic"
              android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    />


</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: User user = mCinematlasApp.getUser(); can be returning null

Comment: @Bäda I have already checked the values of user, and it doesn't return null. Same for navView, it isn't null either.

Comment: One of these variables:nav_nom, nav_username, nav_correu is returning null, check your xml

Comment: @maga can you show your xml file?

Comment: @BitaMirshafiee I have updated my post,but I don't think that has something to do because I have already used this exact code for another activity.

Comment: @Bäda I've already updated it.

Comment: If the XML you've labeled "my navigation drawer code" is `navigation_drawer_header`, then you need to find the `View`s in it a little differently. Have a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33699825).

Comment: @maga you need change "nav_imatge = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.navDrawer_imgPerfil);" to "nav_imatge = (CircleImageView)findViewById(R.id.navDrawer_imgPerfil);

Answer (score 1):

Just found out I had to find the navigation view View in order to "findViewById" just like this: `View parentView = navView.getHeaderView(0);`

Curious thing is that it only happened in this Activity. I guess from all the searching that it just didn't have time enough to generate the view so it just couldn't find the: nav_x views.

Answer (score 0):

check the id of your textviews in your xml with the ones you used here:

```
nav_imatge = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.navDrawer_imgPerfil);
nav_nom = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.navDrawer_nom);
nav_username = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.navDrawer_username);
nav_correu = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.navDrawer_correu);
```

they are not the same

Comment: Yes they are, I just posted my navigation drawer xml file.

Comment: See the error you showed us in your post, it is certainly something wrong with the textview you defined in your xml and the definition of it in your activity, try check this again

Comment: Well I still can't figure out what is.

Comment: navDrawer_imgPerfil is a circleimageview not a textview