# How can I make this picture clickable to redirect any Activity programmatically?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

How can I use navigation drawer (header) picture? My drawer is divided into 2 parts 1 is for drawer option (home, settings, About us) and other 1 is for header I want to make header part clickable that will redirect my `MainActivity`.

[image: See Image]

Comment: can you show me your navigation xml file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NavigationView get/find header layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33194594/navigationview-get-find-header-layout)

Answer (score 2):

Try this out.

```
 View headerView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header_navigation_drawer_social, drawerList, false);
        ImageView iv = headerView.findViewById(R.id.img_profile);
        iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Your stuff
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this in your code:

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
```

After getting navigation view instance. you can get

`navigationview.setOnClickListner();`